# typescript / angular 6 : looping/mapping an Array<any> to Array<MyClass>

Tags: arrays, typescript, loops, angular6

girls and boys, i am struggling with the same problem many times.

i use this request :

```
const url = this.getTheRightEndpoint(tag.name);
        this.httpClient.post(url, this.report, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'BEARER ' + this.auth.getUserSession().access_token }), responseType: 'json'}).subscribe((data: Array<string>)  => {

      console.log(data);    
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));


    });
  }
```

and on the first console log I obtain :

```
[{"BackOrder":"0","BadAddress":"0","CalculatePerfectCompletationTotal":"100 %","CancelByCustomer":"0","Completed":"4","CustomerRelatedException":"0 %","Damage":"0","DeliveryRelatedException":"0 %","DriverName":"Rolly's Transfer","FillRate":"100 %","NoFit":"0","NotAtHome":"0","OrderWithError":"0","PathNotClear":"0","PerfectCompletedStop":"4","PickupDate":"2018-12-04","PlannedStop":"4","Rescheduled":"0","RouteDelay":"0","RouteName":"","TruckNumber":"401","UnableReachCustomer":"0","UnfilteredPlannedStop":"4","Unknown":"0","WrongDate":"0"}]
```

I try to parse it like  this (2nd consol.log): console.log(JSON.parse(data));
and i obtain :

```
0: {BackOrder: "0", BadAddress: "0", CalculatePerfectCompletationTotal: "100 %", CancelByCustomer: "0", Completed: "4", …}
1: {BackOrder: "0", BadAddress: "0", CalculatePerfectCompletationTotal: "100 %", CancelByCustomer: "0", Completed: "4", …}
2: {BackOrder: "0", BadAddress: "0", CalculatePerfectCompletationTotal: "83 %", CancelByCustomer: "0", Completed: "6", …}
```

and so on ...

but my goal is to loop through this object to reach the property of each 'row' ... but I can't ... I've tryed many examples using foreach loop, but the response is data.foreach is not a function ... So I am lost because the foreach function is proposed by my editor.

can anyone help me please ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive broken this down to it's simplest form below where we loop over a standard array and then pull the data from an object:-

I have just pulled out the `Completed` part of the object for you so you can see how to do it.

```js
let data = [
  {BackOrder: "0", BadAddress: "0", CalculatePerfectCompletationTotal: "100 %", CancelByCustomer: "0", Completed: "4"},
  {BackOrder: "0", BadAddress: "0", CalculatePerfectCompletationTotal: "100 %", CancelByCustomer: "0", Completed: "4"},
  {BackOrder: "0", BadAddress: "0", CalculatePerfectCompletationTotal: "83 %", CancelByCustomer: "0", Completed: "6"}]
  
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].Completed);
  }
```

So for your code you will need to use the below script:-

```js
const url = this.getTheRightEndpoint(tag.name);
        this.httpClient.post(url, this.report, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'BEARER ' + this.auth.getUserSession().access_token }), responseType: 'json'}).subscribe((data: Array<object>)  => {

      console.log(data);
      
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]. Completed);
      }

    });
  }
```

Also just a note your `data` returned from your `subscribe` should be `data: Array<object>` as you are being returned an array of objects not strings.

Comment: Thank you Hensler Software. (I am not a office anymore so I can`t try it until tomorrow). i will tell you if that works.

Comment: No problem, I noticed you have been asking a lot of questions but not accepting any of the answers. The community would greatly appreciate it you accepted the solutions that resolved your issues by clicking on the green tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
let json = JSON.parse(data);
json.forEach((v) => { console.log(v); });
```

If data is an array of object, do:

```
let json = [];
JSON.parse(data).forEach((v) => { json.push(v); });
json.forEach((v) => { console.log(v); });
```

Comment: Thank you Msu Arven. (I am not a office anymore so I can`t try it until tomorrow). i will tell you if that works.

Answer (score 0):

A strange behaviour. Your first output clerly looks like an array, but "data.foreach is not a function" makes me think that `data` isnt Array.prototype instance. You can try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` to make JSON library mutate your data into array anyway and then map it. try something like this:

```
this.httpClient.post(...args).subscribe(data => {
      let _data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).map(row => Object.values(row));
      console.log(_data);
    });
  }
```

This is an ugly workaround but i hope it will help

Comment: data.foreach() is certainly not a function. data.forEach() is